# Sql Server Server Group query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Scenario**

I have 4 front-end sql server.

All of them have the same db instances. Data are replicated from back-end databases.

**Issue**

In SQL Management Studio I have registered the servers and I have created a group (called `front_end`). The group can be inquired using the sql editor opening a connection to the servers group.

Is it possible to inquire the group programmatically setting the `USE` clause?

E.g.:

```
    use [front-end]..myDatabaseInstance
    select * from myTable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click the registered servers group and select "New Query" you get a query window that connects to all the servers, whatever you execute will run on all and return combined results.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964743.aspx

If you want to programatically do it, you can use a central management server and query that for a list of servers, and use linked servers to run the query at each location using openquery

http://sqltidbits.com/scripts/query-central-management-server-list